# Discord.JS | Display Users who have a specific roles

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

My name is Tana or Hellen! So am trying to make when a user has a specific role to add him to the embed like this example bot.
What should I do or could you help me with the code? Thanks so much!!

[image]

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far, which part of creating this are you stuck on?

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading this correctly, you want it to only have users that have a specific role? Well, here you go.

```js
client.on("message", msg => {
//<property> can be replaced with role id, to find by id, with role name, to find by name, etc.
var allUsers = [];
msg.guild.members.fetch(); //cache users
msg.guild.members.cache.forEach(m => {
 if(m.roles.cache.find(r => r.<property> === "whatever")) allUsers.push(m);
})
})
```

With this, the array `allUsers` will end up having all the users with the role you chose.

Comment: Why did you put this in a `message` event?

Comment: I thought you were using a command? Well you can try to modify it

Comment: can you help me more about it? it says me about [message] is not defined etc..

Comment: Then… use `msg` if you are using my event listener (`client.on('message, msg =>{})`)